# How to calculate date difference between two columns in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I'm trying to find the date difference between two date columns using the below code. But, I'm not getting the expected result. I'm a beginner.

e.g.
Start Date is `2016-02-18 00:00:00` and End Date is `2015-05-21 00:00:00`, the difference between these two dates is `-273`, but, the actual output is `273000000`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime as datetime

data = pd.DataFrame({'p1':Param1,'p2': Param2,'p3': Param3})
batchNum = data['p1']
startDT = data['p2']
endDT = data['p3']
dateDiff = pd.to_datetime(endDT, errors='coerce') - pd.to_datetime(startDT, errors='coerce')

outputDF = pd.DataFrame({'Batch Number': batchNum,'Start Date': startDT,'End Date': endDT,'Difference (Days)': dateDiff})
```

How do I get the correct date difference?

Comment: If both of your columns are of `datetime` type then you can do this - `(df['enddate'] - df['startdate']).dt.days`

Comment: @Sumanth That worked.

Answer (score 0):

You could try *dateDiff.days* - as a timedelta object, calling it normally may be portraying it in a different unit of time.

```
outputDF = pd.DataFrame({'Batch Number': batchNum,'Start Date': startDT,'End Date': endDT,'Difference (Days)': dateDiff.days})
```